# In angularjs using ui-router, how can I access the ngResource error within $stateChangeError when a request fails in the resolve part of a state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-resource

Here is a plunker with my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/vdctsTcMq4nD1xpUl3pu

Essentially, the $resource promise is rejected because the request fails (with a 404). I know I can access the error within the resolve by simply doing something like

```
AppFactory.get(null, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

However I would like to write my generic resolve error handling code in one place - in my listener for `$stateChangeError`. I know that there is an `error` object passed on this event, however, the error object seems to be empty. How can I get the ngResource error into the $stateChangeEvent error object?

Comment: `$stateChangeError` only fires when moving from one state to another state throws an error. If your error throws in http phase you have to write an http interceptor. See http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2013/09/06/selective_http_errors_handling_in_angularjs/

Comment: The error is being thrown fine because it happens during the resolve phase (which is done when moving from one state to another). If you check my plunker, you will see that the $stateChangeError **is** being fired and the code inside the listener **is** being executed, but the error object is empty. The http interceptor solution is not good for me because I only want to do my generic error handling logic if there is a http error during state change, not for every http error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had the right idea on how to do this - I just had missed a parameter in my listener (the `fromState` parameter) and the `error` object was empty because it was actually the `fromState` object. Other than this, nothing else had to be changed in my code and everything started working. In case anybody else ever needs an example of how to do this, here is a working plunker with my silly mistake fixed: http://plnkr.co/edit/ubOTnw0TuWqzKky2WqxH